# different dates from different views to be displayed in a database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating a website that allows books to be loaned out, i have 3 options for the loans which are 1 week, 2 weeks and 4 weeks,when a user clicks a book they will be taken to a details page that will display the 3 loan options, if you click on the 1 week loan you will be taken the one week loan page where you can confirm or cancel the loan, the page looks like this

```
<?php
use Carbon\Carbon;
?>

@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
<div class="container">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1>1 Week Loan</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>You have attempted to loan out: </h4>
                <h4>{{$book->title}}</h4>
                <h4>By: {{$book->author}}</h4>
                <br/>
                <h4>To agree, press the confirm button, to cancel the loan press the cancel button and you will be returned to the home screen.</h4>
                <br/> 

                 <form action="{{url('loan')}}" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="l_userid" value="{{ Auth::user()->userid }}" id="l_userid">
                        <input type="hidden" name="l_f_name" value="{{ Auth::user()->f_name }}" id="l_f_name">
                        <input type="hidden" name="l_l_name" value="{{ Auth::user()->l_name }}" id="l_l_name">
                        <input type="hidden" name="l_bookid" value="{{$book->bookid}}" id="l_bookid">
                        <input type="hidden" name="l_title" value="{{$book->title}}" id="l_title">    
                        <input type="hidden" name="ddate" value="" id="ddate">  

                            <input type="submit" name="requaestbtn" value="Confirm">
                        </form>

                <a href="{{url('home')}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                        Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

@endsection

on each loan page there will be the hidden input types that will send the data to the controller but i want the 'ddate' hidden input to have the value of 1 week from now if the user is on the 1 week loan page, 2 weeks from now if they are on the 2 week loan page etc.,

this is the function i have in my controller:

public function loan(Request $request)
    {

```
    $loan = new Loan();
    $loan->userid = $request->l_userid;
    $loan->f_name = $request->l_f_name;
    $loan->l_name = $request->l_l_name;
    $loan->bookid = $request->l_bookid;
    $loan->title = $request->l_title;
    $loan->startdate = Carbon::now();
    $loan->duedate = $request->ddate
    $loan->save();
    return view('home');
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, what can I put in the hidden input: 'ddate' so that it has the value of the correct date (7, 14 or 28 days from now(depending on which loan view they are currently on)) I have tried using the carbon package in a few different ways but I always get an error saying that 'ddate' can't be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution to your question is that you can set the value to a number corresponding to the number of weeks of loan period. In your case the values are 1, 2 and 4. Then in the controller you can generate a date based on the loan period number you've received.

But at the same time i have to warn you about the bad practises you're following. Your form can be edited by the user to loan a book as another person. Never send the user information in the form, it can be edited by the end user. Instead use the currently logged in user's info in the controller directly.

```
<form action="{{url('loan')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="l_bookid" value="{{$book->bookid}}" id="l_bookid">
    <input type="hidden" name="l_title" value="{{$book->title}}" id="l_title">
    <input type="hidden" name="ddate" value="1" id="ddate">
    <input type="submit" name="requaestbtn" value="Confirm">
</form>

public function loan(Request $request)
{
    $loanWeeks = min($request->ddate, 4);

    $loan = new Loan();
    $loan->userid = auth()->user()->userid;
    $loan->f_name = auth()->user()->f_name;
    $loan->l_name = auth()->user()->l_name;
    $loan->bookid = $request->l_bookid;
    $loan->title = $request->l_title;
    $loan->startdate = Carbon::now();
    $loan->duedate = Carbon::now()->addWeeks($loanWeeks);
    $loan->save();

    return view('home');
}
```

I've also added a small check to make sure the user can only lease the book for maximum of 4 weeks. If you don't add this check then the end user can again edit the value and loan the books for however long they want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just put in the view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ddate" value="1" id="ddate">
```

and then in the controller:

```
$loan->duedate = Carbon::now()->addWeeks($request->ddate);
```